# Find first element in list that contains a specific character

Tags: python

Im trying to find in the following string a way to get out the $30K and I would always want the first occurance of a $ (dollar sign) but bring through the full value

```
text = 'My 82 Benchmark $30K 1000m S7 $23'

text_string = (text.split()) 
text_string
```

Output = `['My', '82', 'Benchmark', '$30K', '1000m', 'S7', '$23']`

I have tried this code

```
for i in text_string: 
    if('$' in i) : 
        print ("Element Exists")
```

This seems to know that it exists but not which one it exists in

Comment: You could filter it after splitting, e.g. `[s for s in text_string if '$' in s]`  This would give `['$30k', '$23']`  You could then check to see that it's non-empty, and just extract the first element.

Comment: Hey Tom, cheers mate, What would the s  in s for s stand for?

Comment: `s` is assigned to each string in the list, so it's the iteration variable in the list comprehension.  The `if` condition filters out the values that don't meet the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get what you want by using `re` module

```
import re
```

To get the first occurrence you can do:

```
m = re.search('([$][0-9]+K?)', text)
print(m.group(0))
```

And if you want all occurrences you can do:

```
re.findall('([$][0-9]+K?)', text)
```

To get a list with all matches. Hope it helps.

Comment: This has been really awesome and helpful and put me on to looking into regular expressions which I think is a better way of solving my problem than how I was originally looking at solving it...     Thanks for your time mate

Comment: @RobPorter you're welcome. Regular expressions are a thing :)

Answer (score 1):

List-comprehensions are little overkill, use generator:

```
next((x for x in text.split() if '$' in x), '')
```

**In code**:

```
text = 'My 82 Benchmark $30K 1000m S7 $23'

print(next((x for x in text.split() if '$' in x), ''))
# 30K
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything correctly, you just need to print the variable.
If you just want the first value, then you can use break to escape the loop.
This stops the loop once it reaches the desired value.

This code is fixed and printed $30.

```
text = 'My 82 Benchmark $30K 1000m S7 $23'

text_string = text.split()

print(text_string)
for i in text_string: 
    if '$' in i: 
        print(i) 
        break
```

I also removed the extra bracket in your code, and a space between print and open (

update

I will also try to explain what Tom Karzes said in a small answer here.

Tom Karzes said use list comprehension. To list comprehension the code is

```
strings = [s for s in text_string if '$' in s]
if len(strings) > 0:
    print(strings[0])
```

list comprehension is a fast way of making lists. Here you go through all the strings in text_string list, and collect only the strings that have a `$` character in it (see `if '$' in s`).
This way you get a string list, where all strings have a `$` character in it. You can now check if size is more than 0, using `len` and then print first the item in string list.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you say. Can you give an example ? I'm very sorry if my answer wrong, I will correct it.

Comment: And thank you for fixing my english. I'm not good in english.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on the "$" before splitting on spaces:

```
"$"+text.split("$",1)[1].split()[0]
```

Comment: maybe `"$"+text.split("$",1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0] ` is a little better.

Comment: How could this be applied if I was using a df in pandas

Comment: I tried this code to do the same on a dataframe in pandas but getting a error , the code works fine straight from a text string though "$"+df["column_name"].str.split("$",1)[1].split(' ', 1)[0]

Comment: Im not familiar with pandas but I believe a regular expression with the extract function might work for you : `df.str.extract(r"\$[^ ]*")`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the first element that has a $ symbol in it then you can simply break out of the loop.

```
text = 'My 82 Benchmark $30K 1000m S7 $23'
text_string = text.split()
print(text_string)
for i in text_string: 
    if '$' in i: 
        print(i) 
        break
```